# How to proceed when reviewing questions with helpful comments

Tags: discussion, reviewing

When reviewing I've found cases similar to [this incomplete answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/130703/247), where there is a comment explaining how to improve it. What is the correct procedure?
Should I upvote the comment? Should I "Looks good" it so it is managed by the votes alone?

Comment: Upvoting the comment counts as a review action.

Comment: We're talking about Low Quality queue here, right?

Comment: @3ventic Not necessarily, there could be similar cases in first posts and late answers.

Comment: Generally, if I know the comment is correct (I.e. its a game I play), I edit it in. Otherwise I upvote it.

Comment: @HenryHey In first posts and late answers, you can use "I'm done" after up-voting a comment. In low quality posts you need to decide whether it "Looks good" or you want to "Recommend deletion".

Comment: @3ventic Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @HenryHey It's not really an answer, it's something I'm struggling with and wondering about, since some of the low quality answers don't look good, but aren't really qualified for deletion either..